# Quantize Integers into discrete buckets

Tags: d3.js, charts, quantile, quantization

I have a list of ~7500 items which all have a similar signature:

```
{
    revenue: integer,
    title: string,
    sector: string
}
```

The revenue will range from 0 to ~1 Billion. I'd like to construct a scale such that, given a particular company's revenue..it returns its position relative to the following 'buckets':

```
$0-5 Million
$5-10 Million
$10-25 Million
$25-50 Million
$50-100 Million
$100-250 Million
> $250 Million
```

I believe I should be able to accomplish this with either a quantize or quantile scale in d3, but have had difficulties getting the expected results. So far, I have something like:

```
var max_rev = 1000000000 // 1 Billion
scale = d3.scale.quantize().domain(_.range(max_rev)).range([5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000])
```

One obvious issue is calling _.range(max_rev) creates an array 1 billion items long, so I'm wondering how I can do that more effectively (something like .domain([0, 1000000000])?)

What would be the best way to define this scale so that, scale(75000000) would return 50000000. Once I have that, I could check it against a hash and return the correct label:

```
{
    ...
    ...
    50000000: "$50-100 Million",
    100000000: "$100-250 Million",
    ...
```

}

Thanks so much! Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quantize scale won't work in this case, as your domain and range are not split uniformly.  Instead, you can use a [threshold](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales) scale.

Here's an example:

```js
var dollars = d3.format("$,d"),
  data = d3.range(100).map(function(d, i) {
      return {
          revenue: parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000),
          title: "Company " + i,
          sector: "Sector " + parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
      }
  }),
  quantize = d3.scale.threshold()
                     .domain([5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000])
                     .range([0, 5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000]);

var table = d3.select("#info").append("table");

table.append("thead").append("tr").selectAll("th")
    .data(['company', 'sector', 'revenue', 'quantized_revenue'])
  .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

var rows = table.append("tbody").selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class", "company")

rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return d.title;
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return d.sector;
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return dollars(d.revenue);
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return dollars(quantize(d.revenue));
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
thead {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
```

The interesting bits are:

```
  quantize = d3.scale.threshold()
                     .domain([5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000])
                     .range([0, 5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000]);
```

The `domain` sets the threshold values that the input values are compared to and the `range` defines the output.  It just happens that in this case, the `range` is basically the same as the `domain`, but it doesn't have to be.  The `range` could be a list of color values, pixels to define the height of bars, etc.

You could even do this, and avoid looking up the result in a hash table:

```js
var dollars = d3.format("$,d"),
  data = d3.range(100).map(function(d, i) {
      return {
          revenue: parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000),
          title: "Company " + i,
          sector: "Sector " + parseInt(Math.random() * 10)
      }
  }),
  quantize = d3.scale.threshold()
                     .domain([5000000, 10000000, 25000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000])
                     .range(["$0-5", "$5-10", "$10-25", "$25-50", "$50-100", "$100-250",  "> $250"].map(function(d) { return d + " Million"; }));

var table = d3.select("#info").append("table");

table.append("thead").append("tr").selectAll("th")
    .data(['company', 'sector', 'revenue', 'quantized_revenue'])
  .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

var rows = table.append("tbody").selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class", "company")

rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return d.title;
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return d.sector;
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return dollars(d.revenue);
});
rows.append("td").text(function(d) {
    return quantize(d.revenue);
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
thead {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I had no idea about the threshold scale.